# Can I install PHP libraries with Composer and is it a best practice?

Tags: installation, php, libraries, extension, composer

A few years back I used to install PHP libraries on my Debian system this way:

```shell
apt install php-mbstring php-gettext php-cli php-mysql
```

Can I install these and other PHP libraries with Composer and is it a best practice?

Comment: It's two different things: With APT you can manage PHP modules to enable additional features and builtin functions for all PHP applications system-wide. With Composer you can manage dependencies on other PHP projects/libraries when developing or building a single PHP project.